# Updating Telegram Bot Commands In Realtime

Tags: python, updates, telegram-bot

Telegram allows the commands to be updated using [`setMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands). I can successfully update the commands in realtime based on the user input using a python API, [`pyTelegramBotAPI`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).

However, the problem is the user has to exit the chat with the bot and then come back to the chat again to see the new commands (by typing `/`).

Is there any way that I can have the bot update the list of commands in realtime with the user still in the chat?

Comment: Not an a solution Just a hint.

I have created a bot and set its commands directly from BotFather, and changed them while checking if the bot commands will change. But they didn't. I had to leave the chat and back, for the change to take place. If it can not be done with GUI then I do not think it can be done with Python Library either cuz telegram developers would have added that feature.

Comment: I think it has to do with the telegram-client than with the bot. The client app loads the bot commands when the user enters the bot chat, and will not change them until the user reenters again.

Comment: This makes sense. So until the API adds this feature in the future versions, reentering is inevitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is possible to do this real time if you set the scope to chat with specific user. There is parameter *scope* in *set_my_commands* function. By default *set_my_commands* affects all the chats of your bot. However, you can provide *telegram.BotCommandScopeChat* as a value of *scope* param. See the code below, it updates the command menu immediately without need to switch chats.

```
def _set_menu(commands: List[BotCommand], update: Update):
''' sets the chat commands menu '''
bot = Bot(os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN'))
bot.delete_my_commands()
if update:
    bot.set_my_commands(
        commands=commands,
        scope=telegram.BotCommandScopeChat(
            chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    ))
else:
    bot.set_my_commands(commands=commands)
```

Answer (score 2):

So I tried it with telegram client (on linux and on android) and the commands do not change unless the user re-enters the chat. This I think is because the telegram-client only loads the commands when the user enters the chat.

But I also tried this with telegram web and found that the commands changed immidiately after I changed the command sets from BotFather. The webapp actually did load the command set without me leaving the chat, after sending a single message/command

**So its definitely a problem with the telegram-client.**

Comment: I did try Telegram web, which also does not update the command list. I had to reenter the chat to have it effective.

Comment: @AFPP really? let me try again

Comment: @AFPP I tried again, and it works without leaving the chat. But you have to send one message or command before it works

Comment: You were absolutely right. Do you think if we send an automatic message right after updating the commands, would force telegram to update the command lists?

Comment: same here. Spent much time on telegram own api trsting its superior features against whatsapp but even botfather commands delete and adding won't do it nicely